# What does “discolored themselves” mean?

Tags: expressions, idioms

> Murder (said old Quong)—oblige me by passing my pipe—murder is one of the simplest thing in the world to do. Killing a man is a much simpler matter than killing a duck. Not always so safe, perhaps, simpler. But to certain gifted people it is both simple and entirely safe. Many minds of finer complexion than my own have **discolored themselves** in seeking to name the identity of the author of those wholesale murders which took place last year.

What exactly does *discolored themselves* means in this novel of *The Hands of Mr. Ottermole* by Thomas Burke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is likening *minds* to *faces* by introducing the word *complexion*.

He is saying that faces of finer complexion of his own lost their natural colour ( became whiter), like when you get frightened, trying to name the identity of the author of those murderers.